# The algebraic interior of a convex set is convex

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-analysis

I'm reading the concept of *algebraic interior* in which I tried to prove $2$ basic results to strengthen my understanding. Could you have a check if my proofs are fine?

---

Let $X$ be a vector space, $Y$ a subspace of $X$, and  $A \subset X$.

- Then *algebraic interior of $A$ with respect to $Y$* is defined as
  $$
  \operatorname{aint}_{Y} (A) := \{x \in X \mid \forall y\in Y, \exists t >0: [x, x+t y] \subset A \}.
  $$
  Clearly,  $\operatorname{aint}_{Y} (A)  \subset A$. If $A$ is convex, then the above definition reduces to
  $$
  \operatorname{aint}_{Y} (A) = \{x \in X \mid \forall y\in Y, \exists t >0: x+t y \in A \}.
  $$
- The *algebraic interior of $A$* is defined as
  $$
  \operatorname{aint} (A) := \operatorname{aint}_{X} (A).
  $$

---

**Theorem 1:** $x \in \operatorname{aint} (A)$ if and only if $x \in \operatorname{aint}_{L} (A)$ for every line $L \subset X$ passing through $x$.

*Proof:* Because $L \subset X$, so $\operatorname{aint} (A) =\operatorname{aint}_{X} (A) \subset \operatorname{aint}_{L} (A)$ for every line $L \subset X$ passing through $x$.

Next we prove the converse direction. We fix $x\in X$ such that $x \in \operatorname{aint}_{L} (A)$ for every line $L \subset X$ passing through $x$. Let $y \in X$ and $L$ the line connecting $x,y$, i.e., $L = \operatorname{conv} \{x, y\}$. Then $x \in \operatorname{aint}_{L} (A)$. In particular, $y \in L$, so $\exists t>0$ such that $[x, x+ty] \subset A$. It follows that $x \in \operatorname{aint} (A)$.

**Theorem 2:** Let $A$ be a convex subset of a vector space $X$. If $x \in \operatorname{aint} (A)$ and $y\in A$, then $[x, y) \subset \operatorname{aint} (A)$. In particular, $\operatorname{aint} (A)$ is convex.

*Proof:* Let $\lambda \in (0, 1]$ and $z := \lambda x+(1-\lambda)y \in [x, y)$. Fix $w\in X$. There is $t>0$ such that $x+tw \in A$. We want to find $t'>0$ such that $z+t'w = \lambda(x+tw) +(1-\lambda)y + (t'-\lambda t)w\in A$. It suffices to take $t' := \lambda t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thm 1: main idea is there, although a bit tersely written. Only issue: how do you define a line in this class? $L=\textrm{conv}(x,y)$ makes it look like a line segment, not a line with infinite lenth

Thm 2: checks out, but could be made clearer by just removing the $(t'-\lambda t)w$ term entirely.

Comment: You are right. It should be $L = \operatorname{aff} \{x, y\}$.